# BluetoothError: (111, 'Connection refused')

Tags: bluetooth, pi-4

I'm trying to connect raspberry pi 4 to my ubuntu laptop. I setup a rfcomm server on my laptop, the code is given below:

```
import bluetooth

server_sock = bluetooth.BluetoothSocket(bluetooth.RFCOMM)
server_sock.bind(("", bluetooth.PORT_ANY))
server_sock.listen(1)

port = server_sock.getsockname()[1]

uuid = "94f39d29-7d6d-437d-973b-fba39e49d4ee"

bluetooth.advertise_service(server_sock, "SampleServer", service_id=uuid,
                            service_classes=[uuid, bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_CLASS],
                            profiles=[bluetooth.SERIAL_PORT_PROFILE],
                            # protocols=[bluetooth.OBEX_UUID]
                            )

print("Waiting for connection on RFCOMM channel", port)

client_sock, client_info = server_sock.accept()
print("Accepted connection from", client_info)

try:
    while True:
        data = client_sock.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        print("Received", data)
except OSError:
    pass

print("Disconnected.")

client_sock.close()
server_sock.close()
print("All done.")
```

And I setup a rfcomm client on the pi:

```
import sys
import bluetooth

uuid = ""
service_name='SampleServer'
service_matches = bluetooth.find_service(name=service_name)

if len(service_matches) == 0:
    print("couldn't find the FooBar service")
    sys.exit(0)

first_match = service_matches[0]
port = first_match["port"]
name = first_match["name"]
host = first_match["host"]

print("connecting to {} on {}".format(name, host))

sock=bluetooth.BluetoothSocket( bluetooth.RFCOMM )
sock.connect((host, port))
sock.send(b"hello!!")
sock.close()
```

I started the server first, however, when I ran the client, I found that the **pi connected to my laptop for only a short time**, and then the connection broke, and got the error: bluetooth.btcommon.BluetoothError: (111, 'Connection refused').

I've read some similar questions here, but they all seem to have set the mac address for server mistakenly, which is not what I did. So what's my problem here?

Comment: "Connection refused" has three possible reasons. 1. Wrong address, 2 Right address, wrong port. 3. Right address, right port listener not listening,

Comment: Do you ask how to setup a rfcomm server on your laptop?

Comment: @Ingo not yet... Do you mean I may get a hint from that?

Comment: I'm asking because I can't see a problem on the RasPi from your description. Configuring a rfcomm server is out of scope on Raspberry Pi. Can you please elaborate where the problem could be on the RasPi?

Answer (score 0):

I have found the [BlueDot](https://pypi.org/project/bluedot/) Python library provides a more reliable connection:

https://bluedot.readthedocs.io/en/latest/btcommapi.html

It contains an example server

https://github.com/martinohanlon/BlueDot/blob/master/examples/server_debug.py

And an example client:

https://github.com/martinohanlon/BlueDot/blob/master/examples/client_debug.py